# Securing user passwords that must be decrypted by an automated application

Tags: .net, password-encryption

I have a situation where my users are doing work in my web application (.NET 4.5.2) and submitting it.  At some point later, their manager reviews and approves it.  And again later, my automated system runs, picks up the approved data, and pushes into a legacy third party system.

When the automated system (C# .NET 4.5.2) pushes the data, it is doing so as the user who did the work in the first place.  This means that I am storing the individual user passwords for the third party system, so that the automated system can log in as the relevant user, push the datas, then log out again.  The passwords are encrypted, but any developer can look at the application and find the key.   Is there a better approach?

Comment: Nope this may not be good way to implement it. Passwords with symmetric encryption may potentialy open up big security hole in system. Is there anything which is preventing you from running automated job with some service identity?

Comment: Yes.  I am prevented from using a service identity by the fact that the data has to be submitted as the user who entered it, and the third-party system will only submit data as the user who logged in.  I know this is not a good approach.  I am asking if there is a better approach _within the constraints that I have to work with_.